# How to separate array into 4 columns and pass to each column 10 <li> items from array?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays

Lets say there is an dynamic array containing 40 elements (array doesn't change over time, but changes on every render). What I want to do is, loop through this array and return 4  elements, each containing 10 li elements (which are objects from my array), where none object from array is repeated. How to achieve that with JavaScript ?

I wanted to style objects from array with one parent flex container, containing 4 div elements with flex: 25%, and li elements being children of that 4 divs. Like in this example: [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery).
But my images are not static so I can't define each element with typing

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have already tried?

Comment: One possible route you could take is using the Modulo operator. Example: 
```const size = 4
const items = [...Array(40)].map((_, index) => ({
  foo: index, 
  bar: index % size === 0
}))

const grouped = items.reduce((accumulator, item, index) => {
  /**
   * Checks if index/size remainder equals 0 using 
   * Modulo operator and pushes new empty array
   * onto the end for next group
   */
  if (index % size === 0) accumulator.push([])

  // Grab last group and push current item
  accumulator.at(-1).push(item)

  return accumulator
}, [])
```

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I couldn't think my way out of this problem(

Comment: @ZachGover thank you! I can't understand your version because I'm beginner level programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can do something like this.

```js
var myArray = [];
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<40;i++){
  myArray.push("Element "+i);
}

var obj = document.getElementById("temp_main");
counter = 10;
firstElement = true;
output = '';

for(i=0;i<40;i++){
  var temp = '<div class="row">' + myArray[i] + '</div>';
  if(counter>=10){
    temp = '<div class="column">' + temp;
    if( !firstElement ) temp = '</div>' +  temp;
    counter = 0;
  }
  output += temp;
  firstElement = false;
  counter++;
}

output += '</div>'; //closing last column
obj.innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.row{
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10;
  padding-right:5;
  width:100%;
}

.column{
  display:block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0px;
  width:25%;
  border:1px red solid;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
}

#temp_main{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="temp_main">

</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: hey! thank you very much it works as I wanted to)